# I need a formula that states if Column D does not equal "Unlimited" then subtract column I from Column D. Got that "=IF(D8<>"Unlimited",I8-D8,0)."

Tags: excel

I need a formula that states if Column D does not equal "Unlimited" then subtract column I from Column D.  Got that `=IF(D8<>"Unlimited",I8-D8,0)`.

Now I need to add that if column D does not equals "Unlimited" but Column J equals "Yes"  or column J is not equal to "No" it should populate the word "Review"

```
=IF(AND(D3<>"Unlimited",I3-D3,0),OR(IF(AND(D3<>"Unlimited",J3<>"No"),"Review","")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(D3<>"Unlimited",IF(J3<>"No","Review",I3-D3),0)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JoseGliha Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.